# SCRAM in PostgreSQL and old PHP version

Tags: php, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 13 and PHP 7.1.

When I open php file via CMD in Windows I have this error:

```
PHP Warning:  pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: authentication method 10 not supported
```

But if I open the file in Internet browser the script running with no errors.

What I have missing?

Do I need to find what `php_pgsql.dll` version supports `scram-sha-256`? I searched but with no success.

Comment: Does your system use a different `php.ini` for the webserver and the CLI?

Comment: Try `>php --ini` and look at `Loaded Configuration File:` to see where PHP CLI is loading its `php.ini` from

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         D:\WEB_Server\PHP\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: Just edited my comment above

Comment: Yes, I'm using Apache and the extension is activated. I have another  near identical server but with PostgreSQL 11 and no errors (using md5 by default in pg_hba.conf)

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the PostgreSQL client library `libpq.dll` that PHP is linked with.

Comment: What version? ATM it's near latest version...

Comment: No, it isn't. Otherwise you wouldn't be getting that error. I am talking about the version of `libpq.dll` of course, not the PHP version.

Comment: The version is shipped with the PostgreSQL 13 version, what version do I need?

Comment: That may be, but you are not using the `libpq.dll` from PostgreSQL v13, since that would work. As common on Windows systems, you probably have a couple of spare `libpq.dll` tumbling around on your file system, and the wrong one is found on the `PATH`. Look for all `libpq.dll` on your system and get rid of old ones.

Comment: I thought that my PHP version was to old to run with PostgreSQL 13.

Comment: This is a question of the PostgreSQL *client*. But it is well possible that you got the old `libpq.dll` from an old PHP version. Try replacing it. But it sure won't be a bad idea to upgrade to a recent PHP version.

Comment: I had linked libpq.dll(ver13) from PostreSQL 13 in to the apache httpd. I have libpq.dll(ver9.6) in PHP root folder. When I replace the old one with libpq.dll(ver13) I have errors that modules php_pdo_pgsql.dll and php_pgsql.dll cannot be found.

Comment: Then you will have to upgrade to a more recent PHP version.

Comment: That is bad because the code in my app can't run newer PHP. But still why the script runs in Web browser but not in CMD?

Comment: If it is the same PostgreSQL server, the only explanation is that they use different libpq versions.

Comment: You can also rebuild your old PHP version from source and link it with the new `libpq.dll`.